# how do i include whitespaces for input to struct array from file

Tags: c++, structure, computer-science

I cant get the input to get the names of countries that are more than one word. I understand that it stops at the whitespace, and I would like the option to sort by alphebetical order if I want, but I can't remember how to be able to take in whitespaces for the `covid19[i].country` and `covid19[i].region`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct CoronaVirus
{
    char country[30];
    int cases;
    int deaths;
    char region[30];
};


int main()
{
    
    ifstream list;
    list.open("country.txt");
    CoronaVirus covid19[21];
    
    for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
    {
        list>>covid19[i].country>>covid19[i].cases>>covid19[i].deaths>>covid19[i].region;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
    {
        cout<<right<<setw(10)<<covid19[i].country<<"\t"<<right<<setw(10)<<covid19[i].cases<<"\t";
        cout<<covid19[i].deaths<<"\t"<<right<<setw(10)<<covid19[i].region<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Shouting (writing many things in all uppercase letters) is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry im at work and we use all caps. Im not shouting my bad.

Comment: i figured it out: i needed to have " list.getline(covid19[i].country,30,'\t');
        list>>covid19[i].cases>>covid19[i].deaths;
        list.getline(covid19[i].region,30,'\n');" in the body of the first for loop.